# Tunnel an ssh connection through an intermediate machine in a single command

Tags: ssh, tunneling

Is there a way, in a single command, to establish a ssh connection from my computer A, through computer B, to computer C, such that I have access to the shell on computer C?

A wrinkle (which seems to rule out simply forwarding the ssh connection using the -L option) is that I have the password to the account on computer B, and the account on computer B is authorized to connect to the account on computer C, but I do not have the password to the account on computer C.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/311447/how-do-i-ssh-to-machine-a-via-b-in-one-command , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/ssh-via-multiple-hosts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understood that you want just to log in to the computer C, not really tunnel anything from A to C. So, this should do the trick:

```
ssh -t computer-b "ssh computer-c"
```

You might have to enter passwords twice, first for computer B and then for computer C, but this can be avoided by using ssh's key-pair authentication.

Comment: Thanks - it works!  If I may be so-bold as to ask a follow-up.  Any ideas how I can scp a file from A to C in a single command?

Comment: That's a bit tricky. It could be done by adding tar to the mix, but if it's only one file and computer B has the disk space to hold it for a while, it's a lot easier to copy it in two steps.

Comment: You can also do this three times! `ssh -t computer-b "ssh -t computer-c 'ssh computer-d'"` :D

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use SSH's ProxyCommand: http://benno.id.au/blog/2006/06/08/ssh_proxy_command

Comment: I can't find a way to make this work because I don't have the password for computer C, and this approach seems to require it.  Open to suggestions though as this approach does seem more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ssh keys, you could generate a new key for machine B and use that to connection from A to B. On machine B, you can add

```
command="ssh C" ssh-....
```

in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. That means that whenever you connect to B with that ssh key, it will execute the `ssh C` command.

I don't know if this works with scp.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `ProxyCommand`

See `man ssh_config`.  I recommend making use of `ProxyCommand`.  Let's take your original scenario:

- Computer A (your computer)
- Computer B (a proxy hostname)
- Computer C (only reachable via SSH from Computer B)

Edit `~/.ssh/config` with the following contents.

```
Host computerb
    HostName <hostname or IP of Computer B>

Host computerc 192.168.35.*
    ProxyCommand ssh computerb nc -w 180 %h %p
```

Now you'll be able to transparently reach Computer C.  e.g.

```
ssh computerc
```

## Advantages of this method

#### More secure

You only need your private key to be on Computer A (your computer).  The `nc` command will act as a proxy in which SSH will encrypt traffic through.  This includes authentication.  It is a very bad idea to distribute your private key to multiple servers (as any compromised server with your private key ultimately compromises your private key).

#### Matches Multiple destinations

One can match multiple destination computers using `Host`.  A single computer or any computer within a specific network (e.g. `192.168.35.0/24` in the above example) to proxy through Computer B.  It also serves as an alias.

```
ssh 192.168.35.27
```

In the above example, it will proxy through Computer B to get to the IP address.

#### Daisy chain proxies

Using this method you can daisy chain as many automatic proxies as necessary.  e.g. you can add a *Computer D* which is only reachable from Computer C and it will work transparently.

```
Host computerd
    ProxyCommand ssh computerc nc -w 180 %h %p
```

`ssh computerd` will automatically proxy through Computer C and Computer B in the above `ssh_config` examples.

Comment: I'm using [ProxyJump](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump) instead of ProxyCommand and it works fine. It seems there are now more options.